# SQL queries in PostGIS database layer using Python and QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, postgis, pyqgis, python-2.7

I want to create some layers queries in my QGIS plugin using Python.
I have find here a [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/238334/sql-queries-in-shapefiles-using-python-gdal-return-none-result/238343#238343) and I try to follow with success (works fine for a shapefile).

```
from osgeo import ogr


filepath = 'C:/Users/username/Desktop/path/clip.shp' # set the filepath
layer_name = filepath[:-4].split('/')[-1] # get the layer name
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName ("ESRI Shapefile")
ogr_ds = driver.Open(filepath)
TEST=2
sql = "SELECT myfield FROM %s WHERE OBJECTID=%s" %(layer_name,TEST)
layer = ogr_ds.ExecuteSQL(sql)
feat = layer.GetNextFeature()
val = feat.GetField(0)

print (val.decode('utf-8'))
```

but that question is for shapefile what I need more if that is layer in PostGIS database.

I know only the connection like this:

```
import psycopg2


try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='template1' user='dbuser' host='localhost' password='dbpass'")
except:
    print "I am unable to connect to the database"
```

Comment: you need to change your file connection to DB connection like https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/180427/retrieve-available-postgis-connections-in-pyqgis

Comment: @Mapperz can you me example ?

Comment: There is an example in the answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/180480/276

Comment: @Mapperz that not have queries I think just connctions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `conn` is your databse connection from your code above, you fire your sql-statement as follows:

```
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('SELECT * FROM mytesttable')
c.fetchall()
```

Where `fetchall()` returns a list of tuples containing the column values from your `SELECT` (implies that you know their order when `SELECT`ing `*`).

Note that `psycopg2` as a database client does not auto-commit database changes when using statements like `INSERT` or `UPDATE`. In latter cases you have to implicitly end your statement with

```
c.execute('COMMIT;')
```

Comment: thnx you  but I have some question how to take current  postgis connection to do my query?for example in my QGIS project I have save postgis connection every time,how to get it to avoid connect again with my python plugin ?

Answer (score 8):

**Adding PostGIS table to a QGIS map**

In a QGIS plugin I would use QgsDataSourceURI from the pyqgis API. Here is some snippet form a project I worked on.

Database connection is wrapped in a function. All you need is the db_params. The password is only base64 encoded; Since the pw is not a big secret and the users where I work are not hackers.

```
def get_dbparams(self):
    # Get db connections params #
    DB = 'somedb'
    PORT = 5432
    HOST = '11.22.333.44'

    user = self.get_userrole()

    if user == GrukosUser.READER:
        db_params = {
            'dbname': DB,
            'user': 'grukosreader',
            'host': HOST,
            'password': base64.b64decode('SDFADSASDFADF'),
            'port': PORT
        }
        return db_params
    elif user == GrukosUser.WRITER:
        db_params = {
            'dbname': DB,
            'user': 'grukoswriter',
            'host': HOST,
            'password': base64.b64decode('SDFGSGSDFGSDFGSDF'),
            'port': PORT
        }
        return db_params
    else:
        return None
```

Get the parameters:

```
    db = MyDb()
    params = db.get_dbparams()
```

Set the datasource:

```
uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setConnection(params['host'], str(params['port']), params['dbname'], params['user'], params['password'])
```

If your using a filter on table with no geometry:

```
 uri.setDataSource("myschema", "mytablename", None, "mycolumn={}".format(myvalue))
```

If you using a filer on a table with a geometry:

```
uri.setDataSource("myschema", "mytablename", "mygeom", "mycolumn={}".format(myvalue))
```

If no filter and no geometry:

```
uri.setDataSource("myschema", "mytablename", None)
```

If no filter and geometry:

```
uri.setDataSource("myschema", "mytablename", "geom")
```

If using a spatial view. Must have unique column. Here called id:

```
uri.setDataSource("myschema", "mytablename", "geom", aKeyColumn='id')
uri.setKeyColumn('id')
```

Then:

```
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "mylayername", "postgres")
```

Check validity:

```
if not vlayer.isValid():
   ...
```

Add to map:

```
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer, True)
```

**No map just need to get some data from Postgres**

I use psycopg2 like:

```
def get_projectid(self, gkoid):
    """ Use a PostgreSQL function to translate gkoid to projectid """
    sql = 'SELECT myschema.mypgfunction({});'.format(gkoid)
    cur = self.execute_sql(sql)
    rows_tuple = cur.fetchone()
    projectid = rows_tuple[0]

    return projekcid, sql

def execute_sql(self, sql, dict_cursor=True, print_sql=False):

    """ Execute a SQL query
    :param sql: SQL to be executed
    :param dict_cursor: Flag indicating if cursor is a dict or not. Use false for scalar queries
    :param print_sql: Flag indicating if sql is to be printet
    :return: returns a cursor
    """

    if print_sql: print sql
    conn = psycopg2.connect(**self.get_dbparams())

    if dict_cursor:
        cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory = psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
    else:
        cur = conn.cursor()

    try:
        cur.execute(sql)
        return cur
    except psycopg2.DatabaseError, e:
        print 'Some error {}'.format(e)
        sys.exit(1)
    finally:
        pass
        #TODO
        #if conn:
        #    conn.close()
```

**Logging**

In some case error in SQL will crash QGIS at once. A way of debugging is connecting to the QgsMessageLog. I wrap it in a function like this:

```
def enable_qgis_log(filename = 'D:\gqis.log', haltApp = False, haltMsg = 'stop'):
    """ Very useful when QGIS crashes on PGSQL error
    :param filename: Filename and path for log file
    :param haltApp: Halts the application with a modal dialog
    :param haltMsg: Message to user when showing model stopping dialog
    :rtype: None
    """
    def write_log_message(message, tag, level):
        with open(filename, 'a') as logfile:
            logfile.write('{tag}({level}): {message}'.format(tag=tag, level=level, message=message))

    QgsMessageLog.instance().messageReceived.connect(write_log_message)

    if haltApp:
        QtGui.QMessageBox.information(None, GrukosAux.GRUKOS, "{}".format(haltMsg.encode('cp1252')), QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok)
```